# Python pandas - How to correctly transpose this data?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am using pandas to transform a Data Frame that looks like this:

```
        Id     Question   Answer
54      49477  Color      Red
60      49477  Base       Standard
133     49204  Color      Blue
171     49204  Base       Extended
254     48993  Color      Blue
292     48993  Base       Standard
```

I'm trying to figure out how to aggregate the data and append data together so that the resulting Data Frame looks like this:

```
       Id     Question    Answer
       49477  Color,Base  Red,Standard
       49204  Color,Base  Blue,Extended
       48993  Color,Base  Blue,Standard
```

Any guidance on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupby`+ `agg` and `join`

```
df.groupby('Id').agg(','.join)
Out[180]: 
         Question         Answer
Id                              
48993  Color,Base  Blue,Standard
49204  Color,Base  Blue,Extended
49477  Color,Base   Red,Standard
```

Comment: Wow, I had a feeling it would be that easy, I knew I was just missing the syntax. Perfect response, thank you so much!